# res.write spanning multiple functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to display domain searching results from a user-search. The flow of the application is:

- The user make a search (could be stackoverflow.com).
- The application returns a result from that search.
- In the background the application keeps searching for other domains and displays the results when they are ready.

I am using Express in Node.js and from what I understand, it would be possible using res.write() and finish it with a res.end(). However, with my current setup I just get a "Write after end" error.

I assume it's due to Javascript asynchronous nature, but I am a new developer, so that would just be my guess.

This is my code pre-res.write. How would I rewrite it the best possible way, to create a res.write stream?

```
router.get("/new", function(req, res) {
    //Strip all subdomains - the post var now only contains the domain and TLD.
    var post = getDomain(req.query.id);

    //Check if the user inserts a valid TLD.
    if (!tldExists(post)) {
        return res.send(JSON.stringify("invalidTld"));
    }

    //I want to replace every res.send with res.write after this comment
    functions.singleDomain(parse(req.query.id).hostname)
        .then(function(value) {
             res.send(JSON.stringify(value));
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
             res.send(JSON.stringify(error));
        })

    functions.checkDB(post)
        //Check if domain has been resolved within the last 24 hours.
        .then(function(value) {
            let promise;
            if(value !== false) {
                console.log("Domain has been resolved within the last 24 hours");
                return res.send(JSON.stringify(value));
            } else {
                promise = functions.lookupDomain(post);
            }
            return promise;
        })
        .then(function(value) {
            res.send(JSON.stringify(value));
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
});
```

Comment: `res.write` doesn't send the data incrementally -- it's building a response incrementally so it can send it back all at once. Sockets might be a good thing to look into to accomplish this particular thing.

Comment: Ah, looks like I misunderstood it then. I will look into sockets :)